# C++ lifetime of objects built into collections

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
void my_func() {
    std::vector<std::string> all_strings;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
        // "loop a"
        all_strings.push_back(std::to_string(i));
    }
    for (const std::string& str : all_strings) {
        // "loop b"
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I created the strings and assigned them into the vector within "loop a". The question is, whether I can access those vector values in "loop b", where the objects created locally and internally in "loop a" are already gone.

In other words, are the strings copied by values into the vector in "loop a"?

Comment: `std::to_string(i)` returns a temporary, so starting at C++11 a move will be performed, not a copy. It doesn't matter here because small string optimization ruins the performance gain, but in a more complex example it might.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the definition of your variable, you are storing `std::string` objects *by value*

```
std::vector<std::string> all_strings;
```

This means the `vector` *owns* copies of the strings, that it will destroy when it falls out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `push_back` will take a copy of the `std::string` and store it in the `vector`.